# Find the minimum non zero value in a matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find a 2d array that represents the minimum values of the 3rd dimension in a 3d array., e.g.

```
a = floor(rand(10,10,3).*100); % representative structure
b = min(a,[],3); % this finds the minimum but also includes 0
```

I tried using:

```
min(a(a>0),3)
```

but that isn't correct? I guess I could sort the third dimension of a and then find the minimum within 1:depth-1 - but that doesn't seem the most efficient way?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that if you sort, the minimum is the second (index 1 if matlab indexes from 0) element, you don't have to find the minimum of `1:depth-1` anymore. But yes, that is still inefficient and there has to be a better way.

Comment: It should be `min(a,[],3)`, otherwise you take the smaller of `a` and 3

Comment: Thanks for pointing that typo out Jonas, I've correct it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `a(a>0)` returns a linear array, so you'll end up with one minimum, as opposed to a 2D array with minima.

The safest way to take the minimum of non-zero values is to mask them with `Inf`, so that the zeros do not interfere with the calculation of the minimum.

```
tmp = a;
tmp(tmp==0) = Inf;

b = min(tmp,[],3);
```

Comment: That unfortunately backfires for sparse matrices, since it can be very costly to assign a value to all the zeros in a (large) sparse matrix.  I realize that wasn't the OP's question- but just an FYI.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to simply make all the zero values very big.

For example, if you know that no elements would ever be larger than 1000 you could use

```
b = min(a+1000*(a==0),[],3)
```

Comment: @Dan I know this is old, but: No, do not use inf. `inf*0==NaN` so this code does not work with `Inf`. he should use `(max(a(:))+1)`

Answer (score 0):

simply assign those points infinity where the value is zero so always the min answer will not count zero ones..... like
a(a==0)=inf;
%then count the min one
minelement=min(a);

Answer (score 0):

remove zero elements from matrix like this:

```
    a = [10 2 0 4 5; 156 1.7 45 23 0 ];
    a(a == 0) = NaN;% not a number
    min(a(:))
    >> ans = 1.7
```